# How to configure elastic apm url in application.yml file in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana

It works just fine in application.properties but it doesn't work with yml file.

This is how I configured in the application properties file

service_name: my-products

server_url: http://corp.myproducts.com:8220

I tried many alternatives in application yml file and still I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.